# How to find the volume by triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I'm new to triple integral and this triple integral volume problem seems impossible to solve, and I have no idea where to start and how to solve it, could someone have a look at it please.

> Let $G$ be the wedge in the first octant that is cut from the cylindrical solid $y^2 + z^2 < 1$ by the planes $y = x$ and $x = 0$. Evaluate $\iiint_G dV$

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: Integrate in the $x$ direction first, then life is easy. The thing to remember about triple integrals is that the first bounds will always dictate from a *surface* to a *surface*. Moving in the $x$ direction, which surfaces would those be?

Comment: @Eduude no I've just started this chapter :(

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks for the suggestion, could you write the first line so it would be more explanatory to me.

Comment: The first (innermost) integral would be $\int_0^y$. When you start off multiple integrals, it helps to have the variable there to keep track of what the boundary sets (be it surfaces, curves, or points) are. For example $\int_{x=0}^{x=y}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi sorry still didn't get it :( , need some help find the limits of each x, y, z

Comment: I cannot do the whole problem for you, I can only describe the process better. Once you do one integral, think of solid object you drew as being squished into the plane. In this case, doing the $x$ integral first means we have to imagine the object being squished straight "down" into the $yz$ plane. From there you have a $2$D shape to find the bounds for. Another common analogy is that it's like shining a flashlight from "above" (in this case from the $+x$ axis) and trying to figure out what the "shadow" looks like in the $yz$ plane.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_0^ydxdydz=\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}ydydz=\int_0^1\frac{(1-z^2)}{2}dz=\left[\frac z2\right]_0^1-\left[\frac{z^3}6\right]_0^1=\frac12-\frac16=\frac13$$